# Cannot read property '$nuxt' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am working on `nuxt.js` project and getting an error `Cannot read property '$nuxt' of undefined` when trying to access an event from plugin.

In `~/plugins/myPlugin.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue';

this.$nuxt.$on('emit-height', (payload) => {
  Vue.prototype.$bannerHeight = payload;
});
```

Importing in `~/plugins/nuxt.config.js`

```
plugins: [
  '~/plugins/get-main-banner-height.js',
]
```

`this.$nuxt.$on` works if I use it in any components but doesn't work in plugin as mentioned above.

In my component I am emitting the height.

```
methods: {
  getMainBannerHeight() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.$nuxt.$emit('emit-main-banner-height', this.bannerHeight);
    });
  },
}
```

So, my question is "How to listen/capture event in plugins"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference app in context of nuxt plugin. Docs https://nuxtjs.org/api/context/

```
import Vue from 'vue';

export default ({ app }) => {
  app.$on('emit-height', (payload) => {
    Vue.prototype.$bannerHeight = payload;
  });
}
```

Comment: Does this still work? Can't seem to get it to work now.